# Best way to check if user is logged-in when he opens the website

Tags: reactjs, rest, express, http, redux

I have a react app that uses sessions with an express server using REST API.
In my Redux store(on the front end) I store "isLoggedIn" in the redux state. Based on that property I show either the login page , or the home page. Now when I open the website, the initial redux "isLoggedIn" state is false, so the question is, how do I check if the user is actually logged in. I am thinking about sending a request to the endpoint for fetching the data I need in the homepage, and if the user is not logged in, I would get an 401 response and then show the login page. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before I get into how you could persist your redux state I would advise(Note This is a personal view)**

1. Going through the boiler plate code of setting that up is really unnecessarily long
2. Best way out for this is using express-session whereby the cookie is persisted for as long as you gave it e.g if you set cookie to be 3days it will stay for 3days
3. I so believe that it's  industry standard working with httpOnly cookie for session handling as this is secure avoiding XSS attacks and CSRF attacks

**Either way below is your solution to persisting Redux Store**

So with persisting your redux state you can look into something like this

1. First run **npm install redux-persist** or **yarn add redux-persist**

**Now  time to create your redux store**

So now when you create your redux store with **createStore** you want to pass your **createStore** function  a `persistReducer` Once your store is created, pass it to the persistStore function, which will make sure that your redux state is persisted

**Implementation below**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import rootReducer from './reducers'; 
//Import above comes from a file **reducers** which has the combineReducers
// basically based on this code snippet
// I have my combineReducer object in another folder hope that it 
//makes sense. Avoided to write it here to keep code short to show 
//more of setup in  store persisiting

const persistStoreConfigs = {
 key: 'root',
 storage: myAppStorage,
 stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 
};

const persistantReducer = persistReducer(persistStoreConfigs, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(persistantReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**Now passing the store to the App level**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';

// This are coming from the store code above that we made 
import { persistor, store } from './store';
// This are basically your Custom Componentd
import { HomePage, LoadingView } from './components';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      // the loading and persistor props are both required!
      // Noting that the LoadingView is a custom component
      // But the persistor isn't
      //The main aim of this two props is to delay the rendering of your app UI until the persited state is retrieved hence the loading screen component
      <PersistGate loading={<LoadingView />} persistor={persistor}>
        <HomePage />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```